# Scala Spark read json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

My code like as below

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Json Test").setMaster("local[*]") 
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf) 
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) 
import sqlContext.implicits._

val path = "/path/log.json" 
val df = sqlContext.read.json(path)
df.show()
```

Sample json data

{"IFAM":"EQR","KTM":1430006400000,"COL":21,"DATA":[{"MLrate":"30","Nrout":"0","up":null,"Crate":"2"}, {"MLrate":"31","Nrout":"0","up":null,"Crate":"2"},{"MLrate":"30","Nrout":"5","up":null,"Crate":"2"},{"MLrate":"34","Nrout":"0","up":null,"Crate":"4"},{"MLrate":"33","Nrout":"0","up":null,"Crate":"2"},{"MLrate":"30","Nrout":"8","up":null,"Crate":"2"}]}

In scala ide occur error ,I can not understand this:

> INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is
>   'file:/C:/Users/ben53/workspace/Demo/spark-warehouse/'. Exception in
>   thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.DefaultSource could not be instantiated
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)    at
>   scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:575)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:251)
>     at com.dataflair.spark.QueryLog$.main(QueryLog.scala:27)    at
>   com.dataflair.spark.QueryLog.main(QueryLog.scala) Caused by:
>   java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type Exception Details:   Location:
>       org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;[Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelation;
>   @35: areturn   Reason:
>       Type 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/OrcRelation' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to
>   'org/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelation' (from method
>   signature)   Current Frame:
>       bci: @35
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/DefaultSource', 'org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext', '[Ljava/lang/String;',
>   'scala/Option', 'scala/Option', 'scala/collection/immutable/Map' }
>       stack: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/OrcRelation' }   Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: b200 1c2b c100 1ebb 000e 592a b700 22b6
>       0x0000010: 0026 bb00 2859 2c2d b200 2d19 0419 052b
>       0x0000020: b700 30b0
>
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)   ... 20 more
>
> ---

Comment: Is your json valid?

Comment: can you share your pom file or sbt file and sample of json file ?

Comment: ya, it a valid json, i'm compiled and running using eclipse scala ide scala version 2.1

Answer (score 1):

The path should be correct. But the provided JSON is invalid. Please correct the sample JSON and then try. 
You can validate the JSON on https://jsonlint.com/

It shows the invalid portion of the JSON.

Though I tried the sample and got the output as below:

```
    +---+--------------------+----+-------------+
|COL|                DATA|IFAM|          KTM|
+---+--------------------+----+-------------+
| 21|[[2,30,0,null], [...| EQR|1430006400000|
+---+--------------------+----+-------------+
```

The code used is below:

```
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Json Test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val path = "/home/test/Desktop/test.json"
    val df = sqlContext.read.json(path)
    df.show()
  }
}
```

Comment: json is correct. I had already tested it and formed dataframe with the above code and json. :)

Comment: the json i updated was correct, i think admin edit wrongly on the json part, the error seem like not about json format, it about the spark setting

Comment: The answer was useful because I had a problem at my json and I was not aware of it! Dataset was getting populated by null but now it is correctly being populated.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your path is not right. Check if the file is present at the path specified. Json is valid.